# R Programming Need String based unique solution for splitting huge text

Tags: r, string, split

I have a text file with a sample text like below all in small case:

```
"venezuela probes ex-oil czar ramirez over alleged graft scheme
caracas/houston (reuters) - venezuela is investigating rafael ramirez, a 
once powerful oil minister and former head of state oil company pdvsa, in 
connection with an alleged $4.8 billion vienna-based corruption scheme, the 
state prosecutor's office announced on friday.


5.5 hours ago
— reuters


amazon ordered not to pull in customers who can't spell `birkenstock'
a german court has ordered amazon not to lure internet shoppers to its 
online marketplace when they mistakenly search for "brikenstock", 
"birkenstok", "bierkenstock" and other variations in google.


6 hours ago
— business standard"
```

What I need in R is to get these two pieces of text, separated out.

The first piece of text would correspond with the text1 variable and the second piece of text should correspond with the text2 variable.

Please remember I have many text-like paragraphs in this file. The solution would have to work for, say, 100,000 texts.

The only thing I thought that could be used as a delimiter is "—" but with that I lose the source of the information such as "reuters" or "business standard". I need that as well.

Would you know how to accomplish this in R?

Comment: "umpteen text like these", i found that pretty funny to read to myself.

Comment: how does it read now do you know the solution @InfiniteFlashChess

Comment: I made a suggested edit to help with your post, if it helps.

Comment: Do you need multiple variables each for one news entry?

Comment: Also, do you need to separate out the publisher?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read the text from field with `readLines` and then split on the shifted cumsum of the occurence of that special dash in from of the publisher:

```
 Lines <- readLines("Lines.txt")  # from file in wd()
 split(Lines, cumsum(c(0, head(grepl("—", Lines),-1))) )
#--------------
$`0`
[1] "venezuela probes ex-oil czar ramirez over alleged graft scheme"              
[2] "caracas/houston (reuters) - venezuela is investigating rafael ramirez, a "   
[3] "once powerful oil minister and former head of state oil company pdvsa, in "  
[4] "connection with an alleged $4.8 billion vienna-based corruption scheme, the "
[5] "state prosecutor's office announced on friday."                              
[6] "5.5 hours ago"                                                               
[7] "— reuters"                                                                   

$`1`
[1] "amazon ordered not to pull in customers who can't spell `birkenstock'"  
[2] "a german court has ordered amazon not to lure internet shoppers to its "
[3] "online marketplace when they mistakenly search for \"brikenstock\", "   
[4] "\"birkenstok\", \"bierkenstock\" and other variations in google."       
[5] "6 hours ago"                                                            
[6] "— business standard'"
```

It's not a regular "-". Its a "—". <strike>And notice the by default `readLines` will omit the blank lines.</strike>

Comment: Can you provide the `readLines()` option for omitting blank lines? That's not default behavior.

Comment: Color me puzzled. I copied the text to a file names "Lines.txt", issued the R console command `Lines <- readLines("Lines.txt")` and observed the result. I am now unable to reproduce that behavior.

Comment: I too tried this and could not easily omit the blank lines. there is a skip NULL option, but that changes nothing.

Comment: Removing blank lines should be trivial. Could be done either before or after the split. In my case it was probably an artifact from pasting into my editor but R could easily do that if needed (although nothing about that was mentioned in the question.)  If you're having further problems you should post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I could do. I do not like the loop in this, but I could not vectorize it. Hopefully this answer will at least serve as a starting point for other better answers.

> Assumptions: All publisher names are preceeded by "— "

```
TEXT <- read.delim2("C:/Users/Arani.das/Desktop/TEXT.txt", header=FALSE, quote="", stringsAsFactors=F)
TEXT$Publisher <- grepl("— ", TEXT$V1)
TEXT$V1 <- gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", TEXT$V1) #trim whitespaces in start and end of line
TEXT$FLAG <- 1 #grouping variable
for(i in 2:nrow(TEXT)){
  if(TEXT$Publisher[i-1]==T){TEXT$FLAG[i]=TEXT$FLAG[i]+1}else{TEXT$FLAG[i]=TEXT$FLAG[i-1]}
} # Grouping entries
TEXT <- data.table::data.table(TEXT, key="FLAG")
TEXT2 <- TEXT[, list(News=paste0(V1[1:(length(V1)-2)], collapse=" "), Time=V1[length(V1)-1], Publisher=V1[length(V1)]), by="FLAG"]
```

Output:

```
FLAG News          Time          Publisher
1    Venezuela...  5.5 hours ago — reuters
2    amazon...     6 hours ago   — business standard
```

Comment: I like the way you converted the whole data into a neat structured dataframe let me try and see if this solution really works on the huge file. @Arani

Comment: Does not work gives Time and Publisher in the same column V1 column. This is not a good solution. @Arani

Comment: the `data.table` should take care of that. Can you share a larger dataset so that I can check if there is some other problem.

Comment: are there any errors while running the code? Please share if you are seeing some warnings as well. This snippet worked pretty well on your sample.